# Automatic payouts via Paypal

Tags: php, paypal

I want to be able to send Paypal an instruction, via PHP, to transfer a specific amount of money from my account to another given a Paypal account.

Is this possible?

**Now Solved.**

It's called Mass Payments.

Comment: MassPayments is the answer indeed, but you need to meet certain turnover, which I don't. Do you know about other solution, in case one is just starting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option for paypal to send money is only available to business and premier account holders.

> Paypal offers an "auto sweep" automatic withdrawal option to qualified Business and Premier accounts. This option is not available to Personal accounts. When enabled, any Paypal balance will be automatically transferred to a designated checking account every night around midnight to 4:00 AM. This option is a great convenience to merchants with high transaction volumes, so they do not have to log in and manually withdraw the funds periodically. It also avoids the risk of having Paypal freeze your account and any funds within it.

The option for you to make it send money to another paypal account seems extremely unlikely especially using anything outside of paypal itself as that would be very insecure and most likely against their privacy and security settings.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion, but I was looking for a definitive answer rather than conjecture.